# who "likes" my post on Facebook social plugin

Tags: facebook, facebook-social-plugins

I have embedded fb's social like plugins into my [blog](http://www.pavel-kaminsky.com).

it will state things such as  "XXXX and 11 others like this" but it won't show me who.
can I find out who likes my post ?

I tried to google , but no luck..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're ysing the Facebook Social plugin, documented [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/), then you can check the "Show Faces", and this will show some users underneath it.

This will add `data-show-faces="true"` to your code.

**-- OR --**

If you want a full overview of the people that have liked your page, you need to add open graph meta tags to the `<head>` of your page, which will link your Facebook `USER_ID` as the administrator of the page.  This is documented [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/).

`<meta property="fb:admins" content="USER_ID"/>`

Once you've added this meta tag, your like box will appear with a Moderator Link underneath it.  This will link you the Open Graph page for your page on Facebook.  On this page you will be able to see everyone who has like the page.

Comment: didn't work for me.

this is my socialgraph code on my page 


  <div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=XXXXXXXX&amp;xfbml=1"></script>
  <fb:like href="<?php get_permalink();?>" send="true" width="450" show_faces="true" action="like" colorscheme="dark" font=""></fb:like>

I've added <meta property="fb:admins" content="USER_ID"/> to the head, 
but results still looks like [**this**](http://imgur.com/HaxHZ)  

so you see "11 people liked this" but only 1 picture,
even though i am connected there is no moderator link underneath

Comment: Coulton, any chance for a help?